# how to hide the comma data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem how to hide the comma when the field got the value with comma. For example if I have many `ADDRESS`. Anyone got the idea? This is my SQL:

```
select 
mhn.id_mohon,
mhn.penyerah_nama,
UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS1),
UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS2),
UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS3),
UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS4)
from mohon mhn,
kod_negeri kn
where 
mhn.penyerah_kod_negeri = kn.kod(+)
and mhn.id_mohon = :p_id_mohon
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and expected results?  I'm not sure what you mean by "hide the comma".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *remove* commas from strings using the replace function.  Something like:

```
select mhn.id_mohon, mhn.penyerah_nama, replace(UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS1), ',', '') . . .
```

You can concatenate all the address fields into one value, if you only want them in one column:

```
select mhn.id_mohon, mhn.penyerah_nama,
       UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS1) || UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS2) || UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS3) || UPPER(mhn.ADDRESS4) as Address
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data `123 Some Road, SomeCity State, XXXXX` and want to return `123 Some Road SomeCity State XXXXX` you would:

`SELECT REPLACE(column, ',', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the rtrim. For example,

```
select rtrim(upper(mhn.address1),',') as address1 from kod_mohon mhn
```